# org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.4.0' not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

This is my pom file.
I first tried using spring boot 2.4.1 version and it worked fine. Now I am not able to use 2.4.0. Is it because 2.4.1 has been installed in the system and is it not allowing me to use the lower version? (Because any version above 2.4.1 is not giving me any error)

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Comment: *is it not allowing me to use the lower version* no. maven does not a check if there are newer versions in the repositioy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean your workspace, delete your local maven repository (`~/.m2`), or at least the `org.springframework.boot` tree, then update pom and try again. Generally, if maven finds a higher version the dependency is satisfied.

Also, [2.4.1](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-loader) is the latest (highest) release as of today.

Answer (score 0):

I am using IntelliJ and I tried deleting all the libraries related to spring boot 2.4.1 (File -> Project Structure -> Libraries) and then updated the version of spring boot in pom file to 2.4.0 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am using intelliJ and editing only one line solved my problem.

previous line

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

after updating

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me to **update Local repository** under:

IntelliJ > File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Repositories

I wanted to updated from 2.5.0 to 2.5.3 and I got the "not found" msg. After the update the err msg disappeared.